# Is empty plot a scaling issue due to the huge difference in my y values?

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib

This is data taken from a mat file, for which I am meant to apply interpolation techniques in various ways. I wanted to see what the graph looks like with no interpolation applied, but I keep getting blank plots as in the end. ca_i and t are both (1,25) numpy arrays. I'm thinking it may be an issue in how big the difference is in the ca_i scale. This class is in MATLAB, but I am using Python to get more accustomed to the syntax and the differences between them.

This is the code I used:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ca_i = np.array([0.0,0.0018600003438189192,0.0002590223247024505,4.2933247094276643e-05,1.01517329122632e-06,2.2000181987561245e-08,3.1829754066400425e-09,9.251619028714474e-12,1.3077449672199555e-12,3.6241917918406e-15,1.8421082461592794e-13,5.06566621963767e-16,9.840901934293446e-18,3.649674529308416e-21,9.64374923981959e-24,2.5298107231198704e-26,2.3519077811337855e-32,4.429035906892334e-34,1.1414882447414905e-36,4.016168548404073e-40,1.9241495055371506e-44,3.595405959272557e-46,9.170496181343466e-49,1.2525305730959068e-49,5.939334658820937e-54])

t = np.array([0.0,0.8,2.0,3.0,5.0,7.0,8.0,11.0,12.0,15.0,13.0,16.0,18.0,22.0,25.0,28.0,35.0,37.0,40.0,44.0,49.0,51.0,54.0,55.0,60.0])

plt.plot(t,ca_i)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Unable to repro: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cH6PE.png

Comment: I see, may be an issue when I'm loading in the original MAT file data and converting that into np.arrays using the keys then. When I used the data typed out it work without an issue. Thank you! I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong but it's at least a sense of reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting different limits on the graph.

```py
plt.ylim(0, 0.000025)
plt.show()
```